# Missing empty line with manual tag between paragraphs in restructuredText

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

My restructuredText markup looks like this:

```
`pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus404Error: NOT FOUND`
    The entity you are looking for does not exist.  Check that your identifier is still pointing to the item you are looking for.

`pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus414Error: TOO LARGE`
    The query string you are using is too long.  Break it up in smaller pieces.

.. _Scopus429Error:

`pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus429Error: QUOTA EXCEEDED`
    Your provided API key's weekly quota has been depleted.  If you provided multiple keys in your :doc:`configuration file <../configuration>`, this means all your keys are depleted.  In this case, wait up to week until your API key's quota has been reset.
```

In the output I miss a blank line right where I put the manual `_Scopus429Error` tag:

[image: Missing line between paragraphs]

For a live view click [here](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/access.html#error-messages).

What can I do about this? I tried adding a `|`, but the resulting space is way too large.

Comment: I can reproduce this with the alabaster theme. But it looks OK with other themes, for example nature and sphinxdoc.

Comment: I didn't consider the theme to be the cause, good you found out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by Steve Piercy, "The reference label breaks the single definition list into two".

This can be avoided by indenting it to the same level as the previous definition list "definition":

```
`pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus404Error: NOT FOUND`
    The entity you are looking for does not exist.  Check that […]

`pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus414Error: TOO LARGE`
    The query string you are using is too long.  […]

    .. _Scopus429Error:

`pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus429Error: QUOTA EXCEEDED`
    Your provided API key's weekly quota has been depleted.  […]
```

Similar to the [class directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class), the hyperlink target is set on the first immediately following non-comment element, irrespective of nesting levels.

Answer (score 1):

The reference label breaks the single definition list into two, and the theme lacks a bottom padding or margin at the end of a definition list.  You can add this style to a `custom.css` file and include it in your `conf.py` as a configuration option [`html_css_files`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files).

### custom.css

```css
dl {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

### conf.py

```python
html_css_files = ['custom.css']
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it's working (https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#error-messages). What did I do wrong in https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics/commit/ed61a3a4c38c82ba4e14e7e96de528ea86c095bc ?

Comment: Try putting `custom.css` in `docs/_static` and setting your `html_static_path` to `_static`. The correct combination of file paths will copy the CSS file into the build directory. Also check what gets loaded: https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/custom.css